# change click event to onmouseover for bootstrap nav

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I am trying to make the following bootstrap template  work on mouseover event, if screen size is smaller than 900 pixels, or if the device is not a mobile device.

http://htmlstream.com/unify/index.html

I am not sure how this can be done so that the dropdown works on mouseover event for desktops and for mobile devices on click event.

**UPDATE**

I used the following jQuery code

```
//Change Click even to mouse event
$(function () {
    $('.nav > ul li').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function () {
        if ($(this).find('ul').length > 0) {
            // $(this).find('.li').toggleClass('open');
            alert('a');
        }
    });
});
```

It seems i am not able to get to the right element as event is not firing

Comment: Can you add the code that you are talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for hover event

Please check this [link](http://cameronspear.com/demos/twitter-bootstrap-hover-dropdown/#) for details

```
  <script>
    // very simple to use!
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.js-activated').dropdownHover().dropdown();
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in the JS for the click event bound to `.dropdown-toggle` and add `mouseover` (since mouseover will never fire on mobile devices).

Comment: Can i bind both events then i mean mouseover as well as click event so that if a person is on desktop doesnt have to click on the link

Comment: Yes, I meant add not replace. Sorry if that wasn't clear. Eg. in jQuery you'd do: `$('.dropdown-toggle').on('click mouseover', ...`